# HDR color scheme in Windows 10 desktop

Tags: windows-10, colors, hdr

I bought an HDR10 supporting IPS monitor (LG 27GL83A-B) recently. So, I basically just connected it to my PC, then went to Windows 10 display settings and turned the HDR option on. It made a lot of difference for desktop graphics. The effect was that the level of white became slightly lower than in SDR mode, but then the actual colors became very bright and saturated. But not like when you just have cranked up the saturation level. The neutrals, all the "normal" colors were basically the same, though more vivid, but not oversaturated at all. The bright colors, like when they were close to the max R or G or B values, looked like they were glowing. The picture was very vivid and I kinda liked that.

Now, I tried to update my AMD video drivers from 20.11.2 to 21.1.1 (and the video card is Fury X). After that, the HDR vividness was gone. No matter if I turn HDR on or off, the colors in Windows interface are mostly the same, even worse in HDR mode: it looks washed out. It looks even worse than my old monitor compared side to side, and the old one is TN-type. When an IPS matrix looks worse than TN, it's not right, right?

Is it a video driver thing, is it some settings or options I can change? Because I've reinstalled Radeon Software to the version I had, reinstalled all the same official monitor drivers and color schemes I had, but I can't restore the HDR desktop effect I had prior to the video driver update. Of course, I've checked all the obvious switches like 10-bpc color format, etc.

Soo... What have I missed? Are there any other options or settings that control the actual HDR color profile in Windows desktop?